# Can the Excel column duplicate values be highlighted with two colors?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet - which has a column say Name:

```
Name
====
X
Y
T
Y
B
Z
X
X
```

Now Is there any Excel function by which I can mark the duplicate values with a color say `"Yellow"` and `"Blue"`. As an example in the `Name` column i have a duplicate values say - `X` . Now I want the one `X` to be set as back ground color by `"Blue"` and the Other two with `"Yellow"` .

**NOTE** All the non-duplicate values say - `T,B,Z`  also need to be marked as `Blue`.

`I am using Excel-2010.`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use formulas within conditional formatting to achieve this.

Assuming data in column A then select that column and first set this condition using the "use a formula to determine which cells to format" option

`=A1<>""`

Apply blue format

Now set this condition

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)`

Apply yellow format

Now the first "X" should be blue - the other two will be yellow - all other values will be blue

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see if this points you in the right direction: [Excel 2010 Duplicate values][1]

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/excel-2010-duplicate-unique-values/

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) `+1` to you. This is the not what I was looking for,anyway I manged it from your reference!